# URI from InputStream

Tags: android

Is it possible to obtain an URI from an InputStream?

If it is a FileInputStream I can create an URI from it path. But if it's just an InputStream, or a PipedInputStream?

Comment: How did you get the InputStream? Did you create it or did you get it from somewhere else? Normally I have to create my stream so I know here it came from.

Comment: @nathan In my case the InputStream is an PipedInputStream. I create it from a UDP socket (DatagramSocket), so I read the bytes from the socket, write it to the Pipe (PipedOutputStream). Then I read it with my PipedInputStream. I wanna the URI from this PipedInputStream.